# Show <apex:pageMessages> in javascript

Tags: javascript, community

How to show apex:pageMessages in javascript? Here is my code in vf page

```
<apex:form id="frm">
                            <apex:pageBlock id="pb1">
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 50px;">
                            <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
                            </div>
       </apex:form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **show them in javascript**?

Comment: Give the alert or store in another variable in javascript on oncomplete  of action function

Comment: Do you have an associated controller as well?  You could place them in a variable then and pass that variable to the javascript.

Comment: How I do that ? Please tell me

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to achieve it

You can assign the the error Message to alertMsg to serve your purpose.

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Js_Alert" >
              <script> 
                    {!alertMsg}
              </script>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class Js_Alert {

public string alertMsg{get;set;}

public SE_Js_Alert()
{

    alertMsg = 'alert(\'Error Msg\'); ';

}
}
```